# Как получить доступ к экземпляру класса из другого класса в JAVA?

Tags: java, android

Есть класс CarData с полями, например

```
public static String crdName;
```

В НЕосновном Activity создаю экземпляр класса

```
CarData car_data = new CarData();
```

заполняю

```
car_data.crdName = 234;
```

и перехожу в главное Activity, где хочу использовать поля созданного экземпляра класса.

```
int CrN = car_data.crdName;
```

Могу ли я как-то получить такой доступ? Как перетащить из одного Activity в другой созданный класс с заполненными полями?

Comment: Как вы собираетесь хранить разные значения для экземпляров своего класса, если увас поле - статик?

Comment: С этим проблем нет - значения легко присваиваются и используются у экземпляров.

Comment: Проблема в том, что статическая переменная хранит одно и то же значение для всех экземпляров класса, вы так и задумывали?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать класс `Parcelable` и отправлять его через `Intent` в нужную активность или сделать его `JSON` строкой через `GSON`, записать в файл и получить класс из строки в другой активности.
Если интересен второй способ - могу расписать подробнее.

Answer (score 0):

Обращайтесь напрямую без создания класса, у вас там static

Здесь у вас тип String

```
    public static String crdName;
```

Здесь вы Строке присваиваете int

```
  car_data.crdName = 234;
```

Лучше тогда уже

```
  CarData.crdName = "234";
```

Здесь у вас опять int

```
  int CrN = car_data.crdName;
```

Можно так попробовать

```
   int CrN = Integer.valueOf(CarData.crdName);
```

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужно несколько экземпляров класса CarData и у всех должны быть разные значения полей. Поэтому и хочу обратится к "экземпляру", а не "самому".

Comment: создайте внутри Неосновного класса метод, который будет возвращать объект класса CarData, и вызывайте его из главного Активити

Comment: А иногда я переношу в метод сразу экземпляр класса, например вот так: clc_ren.ClcRen(car_data); поэтому хочу понять как тоже самое сделать, но из Activity в Activity.

Comment: NotMainActivity notMainActivity = new NotMainActivity();
        CarData carData = notMainActivity.returnCarData();

Comment: Идея замечательная, только не очень понятно как к нему потом обратиться?  Вызываю Activity так:                                                                                                      Intent intent = new Intent(this, SetScrAct.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, FLAG_SET_SCR);

Comment: Итак, вам нужно передать один объект класса или несколько при переходе из NotMainActivity  в MainActivity? Или уже будучи в MainActivity обратиться к методу NotMainActivity чтобы тот вернул объект(ы) CarData?

Comment: Да, будучи в MainActivity обратиться к методу notMainActivity чтобы тот вернул объект(ы) CarData.

Comment: Вы в MainActivity. в методе onCreate() пропишите 

`NotMainActivity notMainActivity = new NotMainActivity();`
`CarData carData = notMainActivity.returnCarData();`

Comment: Я это уже сделал, но ругается на new NotMainActivity();

Comment: Я пробовал и так SetScrAct.NotMainActivity notMainActivity = new SetScrAct.NotMainActivity();

Comment: Но ведь названия ваших классов вы не указали, они известны только вам, подставьте их.

Comment: Подчеркивает почему то только new SetScrAct.NotMainActivity();

Comment: пишет-  is not en enclosing class

Comment: new NotMainActivity() - это создание экземпляра Неосновного активити, а notMainActivity (с маленькой буквы) переменная в которую вы этот экземпляр помещаете.

Comment: Это я понимаю... почему подчеркивает не пойму.

Comment: @kaaa, прикрепите скриншот ошибки к вопросу

Comment: @kaaa мне кажется что вы не понимаете что делаете.  Для начала вам надо разобраться как работают статик поля, потом ва надо понять что создание активити через new в лучшем случае ни к чему не приведёт, а в худшем у вас появятся новые ошибки. И то как вы пытаетесь писать код лично у меня вызывает негодование. В андрой свои способы передачи данных между активити которыми надо пользоваться. Если затрудняетесь то задайте новый вопрос где опишите что вам надо сделать. И ещё, не стоит обращаться к методам одной активити из другой во избежании непонятных багов.

Comment: Я согласен что надо как-то по другому ( пока только осваиваю java).

Comment: Я согласен что надо как-то по другому ( пока только осваиваю java). Задача сделать каким то образом глобальные переменные, которые можно использовать из любого класса. Хотелось бы в виде отдельного класса с полями, к которым можно обращаться из любой Activity или просто класса.

Comment: Передавать данные между Активити я умею (через intent или SQLite), но хотелось бы понять как передать данные разных типов одной "посылкой".

Comment: @kaaa, воспользоваться в этом случае коллекциями и джинериками. С мапой где будете хранить объекты и использовать когда нужно и где нужно.